# what are the databases are good for user analytics

Tags: analytics

Which is a good database for user analytics/user behavior.

Comment: I suspect someone with vote it negative if you will not provide more information.  Did you Google this? I can see "Google BigQuery" as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres vs. Amazon Redshift vs. Google BigQuery.
As you can see relational database will be the best for user analytics